# How to unit test Symfony 4 Form with EntityType field

Tags: forms, unit-testing, symfony, symfony4

## How to unit test Symfony 4 Form with EntityType field

When I run my test:

> $ ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit tests/Unit/Form/ProductFormTest.php

This is the output in my terminal:

> PHPUnit 6.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann
>
> and contributors.
>
> Runtime:       PHP 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 with Xdebug
>   2.7.0alpha2-dev Configuration: /var/www/project/phpunit.xml.dist
>
> Testing App\Tests\Unit\Form\ProductFormTest E
>   1 / 1 (100%)
>
> Time: 551 ms, Memory: 6.00MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) App\Tests\Unit\Form\ProductFormTest::formSubmitsValidData
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\RuntimeException: Class
>   "App\Entity\Supplier" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did
>   you forget to map it?
>
> /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php:205
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/options-resolver/OptionsResolver.php:858
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php:130
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/options-resolver/OptionsResolver.php:766
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/options-resolver/OptionsResolver.php:698
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/form/ResolvedFormType.php:95
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/form/FormFactory.php:76
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/form/FormBuilder.php:97
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/form/FormBuilder.php:256
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/form/FormBuilder.php:206
>   /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/form/FormFactory.php:30
>   /var/www/project/tests/Unit/Form/ProductFormTest.php:86
>
> ERRORS! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

This error started after mocking the ManagerRegistry class. It seems that in this unit test there is no mapping for doctrine entities present.

Is there a clean way to test a form with "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType" fields?

*src\App\Entity\Product.php*

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Supplier;

/**
 * Product Entity
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass = "App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name = "product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setType(AbstractProduct::TYPE_PARENT);
    }

    /**
     * To String
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "[" . $this->id . "] Product: " . $this->ean . " | " . $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * ID
     *
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name = "product_id", type = "integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * EAN (European Article Number)
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name = "product_ean", type = "string", length = 13)
     */
    protected $ean;

    /**
     * Name
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name = "product_name", type = "string", length = 128)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Description
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name = "product_description", type = "text", nullable = true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * Supplier
     *
     * Many Products have one Supplier
     *
     * @var Supplier
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Supplier", inversedBy = "products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "supplier_id")
     */
    protected $supplier;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set ean
     *
     * @param string $ean
     *
     * @return AbstractProduct
     */
    public function setEan($ean)
    {
        $this->ean = $ean;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ean
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEan()
    {
        return $this->ean;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return AbstractProduct
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return AbstractProduct
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set supplier
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Supplier $supplier
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setSupplier(Supplier $supplier = null)
    {
        $this->supplier = $supplier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get supplier
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\Supplier
     */
    public function getSupplier()
    {
        return $this->supplier;
    }
}
```

*src\App\Form\ProductForm.php*

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Supplier;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ProductForm extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $translationDomain = "product";

        /*
         * Card
         */
        $builder->add("ean", TextType::class, [
            "label"              => "product.ean",
            "required"           => true,
            "translation_domain" => $translationDomain,
        ]);

        $builder->add("name", TextType::class, [
            "label"              => "product.name",
            "required"           => true,
            "translation_domain" => $translationDomain,
        ]);

        $builder->add("supplier", EntityType::class, [
            "class"              => Supplier::class,
            "choice_label"       => "name",
            "label"              => "supplier.name",
            "required"           => false,
            "translation_domain" => "supplier",
        ]);
    }
}
```

*tests\Unit\Form\ProductFormTest.php*

```
namespace App\Tests\Unit\Form;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Form\ProductForm;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Form\PreloadedExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class ProductFormTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var ManagerRegistry
     */
    private $_managerRegistry;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->_managerRegistry = $this->createMock(ManagerRegistry::class);

        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $this->_managerRegistry = null;

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getExtensions()
    {
        $entityType = new EntityType($this->_managerRegistry);

        return [
            new PreloadedExtension([$entityType], [])
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function formSubmitsValidData()
    {
        $createdAt = new \DateTime();

        $formData = [
            "ean"         => "8718923400440",
            "name"        => "Plumbus",
            "description" => "This is a household device so common it does not need an introduction",
        ];

        $productComparedToForm = new Product();
        $productComparedToForm
            ->setEan($formData["ean"])
            ->setName($formData["name"])
        ;

        $productHandledByForm = new Product();

        $form = $this->factory->create(ProductForm::class, $productHandledByForm);

        $form->submit($formData);

        static::assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        static::assertEquals($productComparedToForm, $productHandledByForm);

        $view = $form->createView();

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            static::assertArrayHasKey($key, $view->children);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First your test case should extends from `Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase`.

Then your test should look like this:

```
// Example heavily inspired by EntityTypeTest inside the Symfony Bridge
class ProductTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|ManagerRegistry
     */
    private $emRegistry;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->em = DoctrineTestHelper::createTestEntityManager();
        $this->emRegistry = $this->createRegistryMock('default', $this->em);

        parent::setUp();

        $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($this->em);

        // This is the important part for you !
        $classes = [$this->em->getClassMetadata(Supplier::class)];

        try {
            $schemaTool->dropSchema($classes);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }

        try {
            $schemaTool->createSchema($classes);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }
    protected function createRegistryMock($name, $em)
    {
        $registry = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry')->getMock();
        $registry->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getManager')
            ->with($this->equalTo($name))
            ->will($this->returnValue($em));

        return $registry;
    }

    protected function getExtensions()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getExtensions(), array(
            new DoctrineOrmExtension($this->emRegistry),
        ));
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->em = null;
        $this->emRegistry = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what happens in the $this->createRegistryMock() method?

Comment: this results in a different error: ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry::__construct(), 0 passed

Comment: @Nek : The test should extend `TypeTestCase` as in the OP as well as in the SF documentation => https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html

Comment: You are absolutely right. My bad. Next time please consider editing over downvote ;-).

Comment: @Nek catch +1. For fairness ^)

Comment: This results in "Class "App\Entity\Field" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?" (Field::class being the entity that is used in the EntityTyp like Supplier::class in the above example).

Comment: @Select0r, how did you fix the problem? I get the same error as Select0r. Any else with ideas?

Comment: In my example, I highlighted the most important part. You probably forgot to add it.

Comment: `DoctrineTestHelper` is deprecated since Symfony 5.3 and removed in 6.0. Does anyone know what replaced it or how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

another solution if the one above does not work. Example on another application.

```
namespace App\Tests\Form;

use App\Entity\BusinessDepartment;
use App\Entity\Contact;
use App\Form\ContactForm;
use Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DoctrineOrmExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class ContactFormTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    protected function getExtensions() {

        $mockEntityManager = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);
        $mockEntityManager->method('getClassMetadata')
            ->willReturn(new ClassMetadata(BusinessDepartment::class))
        ;

        $execute = $this->createMock(AbstractQuery::class);
        $execute->method('execute')
            ->willReturn([]);

        $query = $this->createMock(QueryBuilder::class);
        $query->method('getQuery')
            ->willReturn($execute);


        $entityRepository = $this->createMock(EntityRepository::class);
        $entityRepository->method('createQueryBuilder')
            ->willReturn($query)
        ;

        $mockEntityManager->method('getRepository')->willReturn($entityRepository);

        $mockRegistry = $this->createMock(ManagerRegistry::class);
        $mockRegistry->method('getManagerForClass')
            ->willReturn($mockEntityManager)
        ;

      return array_merge(parent::getExtensions(), [new DoctrineOrmExtension($mockRegistry)]);
   }

    public function testBuildForm()
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => 'nameTest',
            'firstName' => 'firstnameTest',
            'email' => 'test_email@gmail.com',
            'message' => 'messageTest'
            ];

        $contact = new Contact();

        $form = $this->factory->create( ContactForm::class, $contact);

        $contactToCompare = new Contact();

        $contactToCompare->setName($data['name']);
        $contactToCompare->setFirstName($data['firstName']);
        $contactToCompare->setEmail($data['email']);
        $contactToCompare->setMessage($data['message']);

        //check the submission
        $form->submit($data);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

        $this->assertEquals($contact->getName(), $contactToCompare->getName());
        $this->assertEquals($contact->getFirstName(), $contactToCompare->getFirstName());
        $this->assertEquals($contact->getEmail(), $contactToCompare->getEmail());
        $this->assertEquals($contact->getMessage(), $contactToCompare->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

another solution if the one above does not work. Example on another application.

ContactFromTest.php

```
namespace App\Tests\Form;

use App\Entity\BusinessDepartment;
use App\Entity\Contact;
use App\Form\ContactForm;
use Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DoctrineOrmExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class ContactFormTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    protected function getExtensions() {

        $mockEntityManager = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);
        $mockEntityManager->method('getClassMetadata')
            ->willReturn(new ClassMetadata(BusinessDepartment::class))
        ;

        $execute = $this->createMock(AbstractQuery::class);
        $execute->method('execute')
            ->willReturn([]);

        $query = $this->createMock(QueryBuilder::class);
        $query->method('getQuery')
            ->willReturn($execute);


        $entityRepository = $this->createMock(EntityRepository::class);
        $entityRepository->method('createQueryBuilder')
            ->willReturn($query)
        ;

        $mockEntityManager->method('getRepository')->willReturn($entityRepository);

        $mockRegistry = $this->createMock(ManagerRegistry::class);
        $mockRegistry->method('getManagerForClass')
            ->willReturn($mockEntityManager)
        ;

      return array_merge(parent::getExtensions(), [new DoctrineOrmExtension($mockRegistry)]);
   }

    public function testBuildForm()
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => 'nameTest',
            'firstName' => 'firstnameTest',
            'email' => 'test_email@gmail.com',
            'message' => 'messageTest'
            ];

        $contact = new Contact();

        $form = $this->factory->create( ContactForm::class, $contact);

        $contactToCompare = new Contact();

        $contactToCompare->setName($data['name']);
        $contactToCompare->setFirstName($data['firstName']);
        $contactToCompare->setEmail($data['email']);
        $contactToCompare->setMessage($data['message']);

        //check the submission
        $form->submit($data);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

        $this->assertEquals($contact->getName(), $contactToCompare->getName());
        $this->assertEquals($contact->getFirstName(), $contactToCompare->getFirstName());
        $this->assertEquals($contact->getEmail(), $contactToCompare->getEmail());
        $this->assertEquals($contact->getMessage(), $contactToCompare->getMessage());
    }
}
```

ContacForm.php

```
class ContactForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name',TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom'
            ])
            ->add('firstName',TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Prénom'
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'Email'
            ])
            ->add('businessDepartment', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Département à contacter',
                'class' => BusinessDepartment::class,
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'choice_label' => 'nameDepartment',
            ])
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Votre message'
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).