# TypeTestCase with EntityType and ServiceEntityRepository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony4

I'm using EntityRepositories as a service in my application. All works fine, but when testing my forms with a TypeTestCase, an EntityManager can't be created for `EntityType` form fields because an `EntityManager` is being injected instead of a `Manager`.

Here is my code, partly based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49879186/1405981) answer:

```
<?php

use App\Entity\Bar;
use App\Entity\Foo;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Test\DoctrineTestHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)  // phpcs:ignore
    {
        $builder->add(
            'bar',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => Bar::class,
                'query_builder' => static function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('bar');
                },
            ]
        );
    }
}

final class BarRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Bar::class);
    }
}

class FooTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->entityManager = DoctrineTestHelper::createTestEntityManager();

        // ...

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $form = $this->factory->create(FooType::class, $foo);
    }
}
```

When running this test, I get this error message:

> TypeError : Argument 1 passed to BarRepository::__construct() must
> implement interface Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of
> Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in
> vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php
> on line 69

I'm using Symfony 4.4.2, doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.12.6, doctrine/orm v2.7.0, symfony/phpunit-bridge v5.0.2 and phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2.

Any idea how I can use a `TypeTestCase` while using a `ServiceEntityRepository`?

Comment: In Symfony's own EntityTypeTest the ManagerRegistry is mocked. Not sure but that could be the way to go: /vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Tests/Form/Type/EntityTypeTest.php

Comment: That's what I do as well: `$this->emRegistry = $this->createRegistryMock('default', $this->em);`. (Now I see the code from that answer is based on EntityTypeTest.).

Comment: why are you using `ManagerRegistry` instead of `RegistryInterface`?

Comment: You mean `\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface`? It's deprecated since Symfony 4.4: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32394

Comment: Same issue here, @StephanVierkant did you found a fix?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: @StephanVierkant any progress yet? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Same problem here in SF5.1 (phpunit/phpunit 8.5.5, symfony/phpunit-bridge 5.1, doctrine/orm v2.7.3, doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.1.0).